# Fancybox record clicks

Tags: jquery, fancybox

How can i record clicks on pictures into mysql database?
It is possible with function **onComplete** or **Ajax** ?

Comment: Yes, you will use Ajax, but you're going to want to google mysql and whatever scripting language you can use on your server, most likely php. I'd advise looking for a pre-built system, because you are a LONG way from a solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a callback for one of the many callback events Fancybox 2 exposes. In this example I'll use `afterLoad` (if you are using Fancybox 1.X then `onComplete` would be a good event to bind to):

```
$('.my-links').fancybox({
    afterLoad : function () {
        $.get('path/to/server-side-script.php', { id : this.orig[0].id }, function (response) {
            //you can now access the server response via the `response` variable
        });
    }
});
```

Note: The above code snippet assumes that each image has it's own ID, otherwise `this.orig[0].id` needs to be changed to something unique about each image.

Your PHP script would look something like this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {

    //connect to DB here

    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tracking_table (image_id) VALUES (" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) . ")", $db) or trigger_error(mysql_error());
}
?>
```

This is of-course expecting you to write your server-side code in PHP.